# Appending Data from Alamofire Not working

Tags: swift, asynchronous, alamofire

I get the Data from alamofire however it's not appending. I think the reason for this is because it's happening Async. Just couldn't figure out the best way to fix this in my code.  Thanks in Advance for the help.

```
 var allItems = [Item]();

@discardableResult func createItem() -> Item {
        let newItem = Item(name: "Grocery", description: "Milk Egg Cheese", priority: "High")
//        let newItem1 = Item(name: "Test", description: "Tes", priority: "Test")
        
        AF.request("https://mobile-app-i.herokuapp.com/list/list").responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                if let value = value as? [NSDictionary] {
                                for d in value {
                                        print(d["description"])
                                    let dataItem = Item(name: d["name"]! as! String, description: d["description"]! as! String, priority: d["priority"]! as! String)
                                    self.allItems.append(dataItem)
                                }
                            }
                            }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
//        allItems.append(newItem1)
          allItems.append(newItem)
          
          return newItem
    }
```

Comment: A simple fix could be to use the completion block to wait for the data delivery.

Comment: The problem is that newItem is returned before it can be set. See  http://www.programmingios.net/you-cant-use-a-value-after-it-has-been-set-by-asyncronous-code/

Comment: Makes sense. But How do I wait for alamofire to complete.

Comment: You don't need to return item, you have access to all items through the array. You don't need the Dispatch block either.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding completion block

```
        AF.request("https://mobile-app-i.herokuapp.com/list/list").responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                print(type(of: value))
                                if let value = value as? [NSDictionary] {
                                    completionHandler(value)
                            }
                            }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Call like so

```
fetchData(completionHandler: {(returnedData)-> Void in
             //Do whatever you want with your returnedData JSON data.
             //when you finish working on data you can update UI
            for (i, d) in returnedData.enumerated() {
                    print(d["description"])
                
                    self.itemStore.createNewItem(name: d["name"]! as! String, description: d["description"]! as! String, priority: d["priority"]! as! String)
              
               
            }
```